# Hello, I had a task to write the function and pass the tests. I Can pass only one test can someone help me with the second?

Tags: python

I had a task to write the function def myreplace(old, new, s):  and pass the tests. I can make it to pass the first test, but I cant do it with the second because off to many spaces.
Is there is a way to do it?

```
def myreplace(old, new, s):
    # Replace all occurrences of old with new in s...
    new_s = ""
    for i in s.split():
        s.split(old)
        new_s = new.join(s.split(old))
    return new_s


test(myreplace(",", ";", "this, that, and some other thing") ==
         "this; that; and some other thing")
test(myreplace(" ", "**",
                   "Words will now      be  separated by stars.") ==
         "Words**will**now**be**separated**by**stars.")
```

Comment: You're saying the results of the test should equal what's to the right of `==`? This is pretty unclear as it is.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
def myreplace(old, new, s):
    # Replace all occurrences of old with new in s...
    if old == ' ':
        return new.join(s.split())
    else:
        return new.join(s.split(old))
```